# HTML not displaying my png logo with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a png image as a logo in a Bootstrap navbar, using the Bootstrap doc snippets, but the png won't display.

My header.php (I'm using WordPress, but don't want the navbar to be administrable) is in the "default" folder, and the logo is in an "img" folder inside the "default" folder.

Here's my navbar :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/img/logo.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-box">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>">Home</a>                   
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Créer mon plateau de fromages |</a>           
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/l-histoire-lepetit">L'histoire Lepetit |</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/le-camembert-lepetit">Le camembert Lepetit |</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/univers">L'univers Lepetit |</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/conseil">Les conseils Lepetit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I tried with only :

```
img/logo.png
```

But it didn't work. What's the issue ? Thanks !

Comment: try adding a semi-colon after your `echo get_site_url()` statement

Comment: Did you inspect the broken image link to see what the current path it's looking for is?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work, but I added a semi-colon on each of the echo get_site_url() though, thanks ! The inspector says that the logo is displayed with a height and width of 0, even though I asked for a 30px height and width in CSS, if it may help

Comment: Yep, it's asking for http://localhost/mywebsite/img/logo.png. The thing is, when I try to open the link in another tab, it shows a 404 error

Comment: That tells you that the file is not located at /img/logo.png.  Can you navigate in your file explorer to confirm its presence?

Comment: Yep right, I should have used get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and the file path from here. get_site_url returns the localhost/website-name, not all the way to the index.php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to track broken URL issues if you use developer tools effectively.  F12 to open it. or right click where image should appear and click on inspect element. then find the relavant area of the syntax. there you will notice if the image url is broken.

also try giving a specific width and height to the img using css. sometimes it may be because it has no room to appear. giving a width and height on the img might fix it.

Comment: Right, I should have used get_stylesheet_directory_uri instead of get_site_url. If I had kept on using get_site_url, I would have had to go through the wp-content/themes/default/img/logo.png. Get_stylesheet_directory_uri + the file path I mentionned on my original post is fine. Thanks !